# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'. How to cast number to string

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rest, glassfish

I want to cast a number to a string in a typescript file in Angular 7. I want to send two data to the backend a id and a name. The backend only accepts the name. How do I solve this error?

```
 public saveCode(e): void {
    let name = e.target.value;
    let list = this.codeList.filter(x => x.name === name)[0];


//This one gives the error
    this.restaurant.restaurantId = list.restaurantId;


//This one works
    this.restaurant.name = list.name;
```

I want to change the restaurantId to a string.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone would simply use  **`toString()`** Method

```
this.restaurant.restaurantId = list.restaurantId.toString();
```

Comment: Ah I did the opposite. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could cast to string by:

```
this.restaurant.restaurantId = '' + list.restaurantId;
```

or

```
this.restaurant.restaurantId = `${list.restaurantId}`;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `String` method to cast integer to Strings like this

```
x = 12;
String(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toString()` or `String()` as below.

```
value.toString()
```

Or

```
String(value)
```

Or

```
"" + value
```